# Rails has_many through and has one through multiple associations with form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to create a certain association. I have a Game model and a Console model. They're joined with a GamesConsole model via has_many through association. I also have a User model.

What I want is users to be able to have games. But I want them to be able to pick one or multiple consoles that they own that game for. So I created an Ownership model that belongs to a user and a games_console, that way it gets a game_id and console_id from the games_console.

First of all, I'm not sure if that's the correct or best way to set that up. But my main question is how to make a form to create/edit these Ownerships. I want the form to be on the Games#show view and to have a checkbox for each console available for the specific game. You'd check the consoles you own the game for and click the submit button. Doing that would create the necessary ownerships as well as delete some if you uncheck consoles that you previously owned the game for.

I've tried playing with collection_check_boxes for the form but I'm not sure how to set it up or how to set up the controller. This association is more complicated than ones that I've used before. Any help would be much appreciated.

My models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :games_consoles, through: :ownerships
  has_many :games, -> { distinct }, through: :games_consoles
  has_many :consoles, -> { distinct }, through: :games_consoles
end

class Console < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games_consoles
  has_many :games, through: :games_consoles
  has_many :ownerships, through: :games_consoles
  has_many :users, -> { distinct }, through: :ownerships
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games_consoles
  has_many :consoles, -> { order(:name) }, through: :games_consoles
  has_many :ownerships, through: :games_consoles
  has_many :users, -> { distinct }, through: :ownerships
end

class GamesConsole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :console
  has_many :ownerships
end

class Ownership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :games_console
  has_one :game, through: :games_console
  has_one :console, through: :games_console
end
```

Comment: Would you explain this sentence a bit more: "But I want them to be able to pick one or multiple consoles that they own that game for. " ? Does every console have a certain list of games?

Comment: Games and Consoles are currently independent of users.  Consoles are seeded the database (and added when new consoles are released). Then Games are added along with one GamesConsole association model for each console that game is available for. The GamesConsole model has a game_id and console_id.  With that you can get all the consoles for a certain game via game.consoles and every game for a certain console via console.games.